# Join two tables together with one same column value without losing any records

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am using Php my admin I would really appreciate any advice or help I am trying to display Join two tables together with one same column value without losing any records

I have 2 tables like this:

**tbladdress**

```
id         Address 
1222       add1
1332       add2
1555       add3
1776       add4
```

**tblcx**

```
name       location    Status
ana        1222        completed
ema        1332        used
ada        1332        completed
```

I want to display rows that from tbladdress where id is equals to tblcx location which tblcx Status will also be join without losing any records

**desired output**

```
    tbladdress

   id         Address     Status
    1222       add1       completed
    1332       add2       used
    1332       add2       completed
    1555       add3 
    1776       add4
```

query I am trying to use

```
SELECT tbladdress.id, tbladdress.Address 
FROM tbladdress 
LEFT JOIN tblcx ON tbladdress.id=tblcx.location
```

but not working and not giving me the desired output.

Comment: What does your output look like?  You're correct to use a LEFT JOIN.

Comment: It looks like you just need to include the `tblcx.Status` field in your SELECT clause.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT tbladdress.id as Id, tbladdress.Address as Address, tblcx.Status as Status 
FROM tbladdress 
LEFT JOIN tblcx ON tbladdress.id=tblcx.location
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Answers with code-only are discouraged as it doesn't help others learn. Please explain what your code does, and how it answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is right but you haven't selected the status column,  you can try this:

SELECT ta.id, ta.Address, tb.status 
FROM tbladdress ta
LEFT JOIN tblcx tb ON ta.id=tb.location